# Как лучше сгенерировать уникальный 13-и циферный код в PHP имея на входе уникальную строку?

Tags: php, generate, штрихкод

Подскажите простой способ сгенерировать уникальное 13 значное численное значение для уникальной строки в PHP ?

К примеру, есть у меня какая-нибудь уникальная строка вида: **mysecretworld_5793**, так вот мне нужно получить для неё уникальный цифровой 13-и значный код вида: **5901234123457**

**p.s.: мне просто нужно сгенерировать уникальный код для штрих-кодов в формет EAN13**

Comment: на гитхабе есть для этих целей удобный инструмент - не помню название, поищите баркод на гитхабе.

Comment: если вы про этот https://github.com/rlt3/php-barcode - мне нужен алгоритм генерации этого 13-и значного кода, а не генератор EAN13-штрихкода.

Comment: нет, не об этом. Я с телефона, буду за ПК, скину Линк. Или поищите именно EAN13 на гитхабе.

Comment: ну там тоже будет генератор. откроете метод, и прочитаете алгоритм

Comment: То, чего вы просите в общем случае невозможно.

Comment: На все уникальные строки уникальных кодов просто не хватит))

Comment: если использовать мой код вначале EAN13 кода, то всё будет уникально ) Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда добавляйте на все штрихкоды одинаковый префикс. К чему плодить сущности?

Comment: к тому что остальная часть штрих-кода должна быть непредсказуемой по возможности, чтобы не подделали.

Comment: @Enshtein обещанный линк: [php-barcode-generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
$tovar='mysecretworld_5793';
$md5code=hexdec(md5($tovar));
$code=substr(number_format($md5code,13,'',''),0,12);
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d00144b8ffed5a2bfbaaaf7ae2c61149c69be7bf)

Но в целом лучше всего проверять коллизии, т.к. длина небольшая.

Comment: спасибо за алгоритм! для защиты от коллизий я просто буду использовать свой цифровой код как часть EAN13 кода

Answer (score 1):

По сути у вас будет производиться хеширование, значит уникальность не гарантирована. А с таким набором для уникальности, коллизии получить проще простого.

Comment: в принципе у меня цифровой код уникальный, могу его использовать просто как часть EAN13 кода - тогда никаких коллизиций!

Comment: ты используешь лишь часть уникального кода и делаешь его не гарантированно уникальным. Если кодов надо не много, то в принципе контролируя уникальность получаемых кодов такое можно провернуть.